# How to Push out Site Content Changes

Tags: ee2

Our Expression Engine site is essentially a Style Guide for development teams. What i am looking for is a good way to push out changes to the folks that want to listen.

Is there a good plugin or feature I could use that would allow folks to subscribe by email to content pages or maybe an RSS feed tracking internal changes or even any internal features I may be missing?

Ideally not all users would need to be Expression engine users.

I've tried searching around but most of the results a I get are change logs for the actual product.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an RSS module that's part of the EE base install. You may have to turn it on, but it's there. You can set up RSS feeds for any category or channel you wish, and it can contain a URL, the whole content...whatever. Here's the user manual link to using the [RSS module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/rss/) (note that it is for EE version 2.7+, but the directions should be fairly similar even for older versions. I don't know that the RSS module has had any feature additions since version 1.5x, anyway.)

People would not have to be EE users to get the RSS feeds. All they'd need is an RSS reader.

There's also a mailing list module with the default EE install, for email lists - but I think that's for building an email list and communicating with them rather than for automatically notifying when there are changes.

I know that there are other modules out there, created by third-party developers and companies. devot-ee lists them and includes ratings on the modules themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to build an RSS feed with an ExpressionEngine template. There are some examples in the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/rss/#sample-rss-and-atom-templates).

In the past I've used [Mailchimp's](http://mailchimp.com) RSS to Email service to pick up new posts from an RSS feed and email them out to users.